# Set items to Combo Box in JAVA

Tags: java, swing, combobox

I have a combo box with options Small, Medium, and Large. These are the properties and want to apply...

The string variable `Pattern` have values `Small`, `Medium`, `Large` and it's add to the combo box `Barsize`

While running this java file, if I choose `Medium` option it got selected and also property had applied but if I run once again it goes to Small option in index of the combo box.

How do I save that....???
I need an option what I have selected in index till Next changes will make...

Coding is........

```
propertiesPanel.add(new JLabel("Barsize"))
BarField = new JComboBox(pattern)
propertiesPanel.add(BarField)
```

Here pattern have the values `Small`, `Medium`, and `Large`......

Comment: Note you say *it's add to the combo box Barsize* but the combo box in your code is called `barField`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> While running this java file, if I choose Medium option it got
>   selected and also property had applied but if I run once again it goes
>   to Small option in index of the combo box.

You need some global place (I'm thinking in a [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)) to keep this selected size so when you show this window again you can set this value as selected in your combo box.

Something like this:

```
public class SizeProperties {

    private static SizeProperties _instance;
    private Sizes _selectedSize;

    public enum Sizes{SMALL, MEDIUM, LARGE}

    private SizeProperties(){
        _selectedSize = Sizes.SMALL;
    }

    public static SizeProperties getInstance(){
        if(_instance == null){
            _instance = new SizeProperties();
        }
        return _instance;
    }

    public Sizes getSelectedSize(){
        return _selectedSize;
    }

    public void setSelectedSize(Sizes size){
        _selectedSize = size;
    }
}
```

In your dialog you can fill your combobox as follows:

```
JComboBox barField = new JComboBox();
for(SizeProperties.Sizes s : SizeProperties.Sizes.values()){
    barField.addItem(s);
}
barField.setSelectedItem(SizeProperties.getInstance().getSelectedSize());
```

Finally to save selected size in your singleton class:

```
SizeProperties.Sizes selectedSize = (SizeProperties.Sizes) barField.getSelectedItem();
SizeProperties.getInstance().setSelectedSize(selectedSize);
```

Comment: In this line public enum Sizes{SMALL, MEDIUM, LARGE} error rasied as The member enum Sizes must be defined inside a static member type. what to do now...

Comment: @RasaMohamed In my rush I forgot to add `static` modifiers. Sorry about that. Please note there's no need to make the `enum` static, you just need to include the class name where this enum is defined: for instance `SizeProperties.Sizes.values()`. Please see updated answer. If this worked for you, please don't forget to accept the answer. See [How does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)